# why is the output the same in both elements when i initialize path="" and does not initialize path with any value

Tags: python, depth-first-search

```
row = [ -1, 0, 1,  0]
col = [  0, 1, 0, -1]

def isSafe(x, y, processed):
    return (0 <= x < M) and (0 <= y < N) and not processed[x][y]

def dfs(board, words, processed, i, j, path=""):
    processed[i][j] = True

    path = path + board[i][j]
    words.append(path)
    for k in range(4):
        if isSafe(i + row[k], j + col[k], processed):
            dfs(board, words, processed, i + row[k], j + col[k], path="")
    processed[i][j] = False

def solve(board):
    processed = [[False for x in range(N)] for y in range(M)]
    words = []
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            dfs(board, words, processed, i, j)
    print(words)
board =[
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['C', 'D']]
(M, N) = (len(board), len(board[0]))
solve(board)
```

the output is

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABD', 'ABDC', 'AC', 'ACD', 'ACDB', 'B', 'BD', 'BDC', 'BDCA', 'BA', 'BAC', 'BACD', 'C', 'CA', 'CAB', ' CABD', 'CD', 'CDB', 'CDBA', 'D', 'DB', 'DBA', 'DBAC', 'DC', 'DCA', 'DCAB']
```

I am confused in dfs function because every time  I initialize path with empty string so the 2nd element of output list should be `B` but it is `AB` , and like this 3rd element should be `C` but in output list it is `ABC`  and so on . Please explain this recurson

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I've executed your code-snippet and it resulted in the following output:

`['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B']`

Comment: The code is working fine i think that your console need a restart.me to run the same code it is actually giving your required result.just restart the console.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPZUl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPZUl.png)